# Unable to load app.xaml using Application.LoadComponent

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I reproduced a problem I have in a project where I need to load an App.xaml using Application.LoadComponent in a small solution with just 1 WPF project.

I have an application entry point in a separate class, which creates the application as follows:

```cs
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    var app = new App();
    var resource = new Uri("/WpfApplication1;component/app.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
    Application.LoadComponent(app, resource);
    app.Run(new MainWindow());
}
```

An exception is thrown on the method call LoadComponent:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in
>   PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot locate resource 'app.xaml'.

I can't see what I am doing wrong, also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336917/application-loadcomponent-cannot-find-resource) answer seems to point to the same solution. And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430642/application-loadcomponent-fails-when-loading-from-an-unreferenced-assembly) one too.

The assembly name is correct, double checked it before asking this question.
I tried the following resource locations, they all result in the same exception:

```
var resource = new Uri("/WpfApplication1;component/app.xaml", UriKind.Relative);

var resource = new Uri("/WpfApplication1;component/WpfApplication1/app.xaml", UriKind.Relative);

var resource = new Uri("/WpfApplication1;component/WpfApplication1.app.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
```

Comment: a downvote without any explanation?

Comment: I have figured out the solution and upvoted the question. I will post solution tomorrow. Cheers ! Good night.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan haha that's quite the cliffhanger, pulling my hair out all evening long already. I'll let it go and pray for your answer tomorrow. Thx in advance!

Comment: ok posted answer without explanation. will post long answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change Build Action of your App.xaml file to Page and run. This will also work.

```cs
var app = new App();

var resource = new Uri("/WpfApplication1;component/app.xaml", UriKind.Relative); 

Application.LoadComponent(app, resource);            
app.StartupUri = new Uri("MainWindow.xaml", UriKind.Relative);

app.Run();
```

Comment: Sir yes sir! That does the trick. I have another application where I have the exact same setup, and there I am allowed to use the App.xaml as ApplicationDefinition. Really clueless why it working in that application, but on the other hand really happy that you solved this annoying issue! Thanks!!